# Should the implementation of value object be sealed?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, value-objects

Following DDD practices, should the implementation of value object be sealed? 
Imagine having some abstract `ValueObject<T>` and the concrete implementation given as `Money : ValueObject<Money>`. Should I seal `Money`?

```
public class Money : ValueObject<Money>
{
    private Money()
    {
    }

    private Money(decimal value, string currency)
    {
        Requires.NotEmpty(currency, nameof(currency));
        Requires.That(value >= 0, $"{nameof(value)} must be greater or equals to 0.");

        Value = value;
        Currency = currency.ToUpper();
    }

    public decimal Value { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// <a href="http://currencysystem.com/codes/">ISO 4217</a> currency code 
    /// </summary>
    public string Currency { get; private set; }

    public static Money Dkk(decimal value) => new Money(value, "DKK");
    public static Money Usd(decimal value) => new Money(value, "USD");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's best practices to avoid polymorphism due to the composition over inheritance advice. In the DDD context there are some cases where it's useful to allow future polymorphism but this usually includes entities.

Value object per definition should be immutable and to avoid further misuse, seal it.

Useful link: http://thepaulrayner.com/value-objects-and-immutability/

Comment: So by design, you should omit inheritance in this case? 
I thought it would be really nice to have some base class to reuse the value object behavior (my current abstract [implementation](https://gist.github.com/d1mnewz/e5735ef37d05de609b6d4c2a902e6ce5))
Gotta seal Money for sure, thanks!

Comment: well you can. the question is: do you really need an abstraction? what are the potential child classes of Money?
I'm more a fan of explicit code. this may lead to some small code duplication but usually it reduces complexity.

Comment: addidtional to this. if you use polymorphism you "open a door" of possibilities which may leads to affect immutability.

Comment: I mean, does it makes sense to introduce base value object class and use it for creating sealed derived classes? I truly understand that leaving an opportunity to extend the class is no good in this case, but the question I'm trying to ask now is whether should I remove inheriting from ValueObject and introduce some interface and make for instance Money implement it.

Comment: you use this abstract class to define hashCode and equals right? i prefer this kind of information on my implementation but this is probably more a "matter of taste". Technically it should work. What would be the main behavior of this interface?

Answer (score 0):

To me, Value Object vs other type of object makes little difference when considering sealing. Countless arguments have been made both for and against it over the years with complex enough considerations that you don't want to add another variable to the equation.

I can hardly see all VO's in a domain model being sealed but all other classes not sealed. If you're going to seal, it will primarily be for a whole different range of reasons (organizational, performance) that don't have much to do with the type of object in the DDD nomenclature.